# Columns that add up to 100% are stacking, not floating

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to learn bootstrap and I've duplicated the container, row and columns in another project but they are not floating properly.  My css is:

```
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}  

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12 { 
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    float: left; 
    }

.col-1 { width: 8.33333333%; }
.col-2 { width: 16.66666667%; }
.col-3 { width: 25%; }
.col-4 { width: 33.33333333%; }
.col-5 { width: 41.66666667%; }
.col-6 { width: 50%; }
.col-7 { width: 58.33333333%; }
.col-8 { width: 66.66666667%; }
.col-9 { width: 75%; }
.col-10 { width: 83.33333333%; }
.col-11 { width: 91.66666667%; }
.col-12 { width: 100%; }

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.row:after {
    clear: both;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container { width: 750px; }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container { width: 970px; }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container { width: 1170px; }
}
```

and the html is:

```
<body>
<header>

</header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12"></div><h1 class="text-center">Test<span><a href="#" title="Contact Jeremy">Test</a></span><span>Test</span>         <span>test</span></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">Profile</div><div class="col-9"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I try to use it one column will stack.  If I change the percentages a little so they don't add up to 100% it works.  But it seems to work fine in bootstrap.  Can anyone see what I am missing?

Comment: It's because of the padding, it adds extra space around the columns which combined with 100% width causes the columns to stack. Column based layouts normally have a guttering between columns and then use calc to minus the gutter from the total % width of each column. So you have a 15px gutter each side = calc(80% - 30px) would give you your width on an 80% col

Comment: But why does this same thing work in bootstrap?

Comment: Because they account for guttering

Comment: Well I kind of thought that that might be the case, but I can't find anywhere in the bootstrap.css where they account for guttering.  I basically copied and pasted the css for .container, .row, and the columns.  I checked again just now and can't find that accounting.  What am I missing?

Comment: The way you could test it would be to remove the padding and see if it still wraps

Comment: Yeah, I did that and it works.  I understand that the padding is the problem, I just don't understand why the bootstrap.css puts the left and right padding on the columns and doesn't have the issue.  I can't figure out where they are accounting for that.  I understand why mine doesn't work.  So I guess what I'm asking is why theirs works.

Comment: I'm going to favourite this question and take a look in the morning as I'm not at my pc right now.

Comment: http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works

Answer (score 0):

> It's because of the padding, it adds extra space around the columns. Combined with `width: 100%` causes the columns to stack.
>
> Column based layouts normally have a guttering between columns and then use `calc()` to subtract the gutter from the total % width of each column.
>
> So you have a `15px` gutter on each side = `calc(80% - 30px)` would give you your width on an 80% column.

by [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020154/alex)

---

> [The Subtle Magic Behind Why The Bootstrap 3 Grid Works](http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works)

by [mfp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6383567/mfp)